# Using matrices in R to associate identifiers with vectors stored in lists

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dataframe, time-series

## Background

I imported a data set from MATLAB into R using [R.matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/)'s read.mat() function.

It gave me a 3-dimensional array of lists, and in each list was a single matrix. Here is an example of some of its output.

```
, , 1

           [,1]         
experiment 5         
reader     "A"          
time       Numeric,20002
value      Numeric,20002
```

Essentially, this array contains a number of experiments, where the experiment and its associated information is accessed by the third index. Associated with each experiment is the experiment number, the reader name, a sequence of time measurements with a corresponding sequence of values at those times (think of a time series but with the time and values split into two separate parts).

Like I said, the contents of the array are lists containing matrices. So this means the entry with value 5 next to "experiment" is actually list with a a 1 by 1 matrix. Similarly, the entry next to "value" is a list with a 10002 by 1 matrix, which is essentially a vector.

Now, I have simplified this structure somewhat by removing the extraneous second dimension of the array, thus turning it into a matrix, and converting the matrices within the lists into vectors. The output of the reformatted array looks like this.

```
     experiment reader time           value         
[1,] 4          "A"    Numeric,100002 Numeric,100002
[2,] 8          "B"    Numeric,100002 Numeric,100002
[3,] 12         "C"    Numeric,100002 Numeric,100002
[4,] 16         "D"    Numeric,100002 Numeric,100002
[5,] 20         "E"    Numeric,100002 Numeric,100002
```

## Question

My main question is whether or not this is really an appropriate way to structure this data in R. I feel like I'm fighting the inherent constructs in R to make this work, but then again, I am relatively inexperienced with R.

The reason I like this format is because the lists containing the time and value vectors can readily be found by their associated experiment number or reader name, which allows for fast subsetting. For example, if the name of the matrix is "e"

```
e[ e[, "experiment"] == c(4, 8), ]
e[ e[, "reader"] == "A", "value"]
```

It seems like I should really be using a data.frame here, but I'm not sure. Another way I have tried structuring it is in a long format using a data.frame, where each of the data points in the vectors are taken out and associated with the experiment number and reader name. This data.frame looks like this.

```
  experiment reader    time    value
1          4      A 1.45650 2.330000
2          4      A 1.96705 2.596625
3          4      A 2.47760 2.863250
4          4      A 2.98815 3.129875
5          4      A 3.49870 3.396500
```

This format is a little simpler to work with because I do not have to worry about dealing with converting the lists in the matrix format. However, I have to manually recreate the vectors for time and value, which can be time consuming when searching through this significantly larger data.frame. For example, if the data.frame's name is "y"

```
y[ y[, "experiment"] == 4, ]$time 
y[ y[, "experiment"] == 4, ]$value
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I basically would go with your last suggestion and use package data.table for better efficiency. However, you don't tell what you want to do with the data.

Comment: In the end, I want to calculate metrics based on the time and value vectors (e.g. mean, max, standard deviation) and then associate the calculated metrics with the corresponding experiment number and reader name. The matrix form appears to have the vectors "right there", which seems better to me.

Comment: That could be done very easily and efficiently with your last structure and package data.table (or dplyr if you prefer). Using your array would be complicated and slow in comparison.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using data.table wrong, but I don't see how it would be slower, unless you mean in terms of script development time. Suppose the data.table is "u" and the matrix form is "e". `Using system.time()` I get the following. `system.time(sum(u[u$reader == "A",]$value) user  system elapsed 1.90 0.04 1.97 ` `system.time(lapply(e[,4], sum)) user  system elapsed 0.26 0.00 0.27 `

Comment: That is not data.table code. Try this: `library(data.table); setDT(u)` then for one reader: `u[reader == "A", sum(value)]` and for all readers: `u[, sum(value), by = reader]`. Read the package documentation to learn more.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was very ignorant. Although the matrix form might be faster for some things, the data.table is infinitely more convenient and is also faster in other areas. Would you like to post an answer or should I?